# Return to mobile site

Tags: support, mobile-web

On my Nokia Lumia smartphone I switched from mobile StackOverflow to full site.

How can I switch back?
I cant find a link or button or some setting for that.

Comment: There's a "mobile" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Great, between *advertising info* and *contact us*. And just *mobile*, no hint of returning or something. Very user unfriendly for a smartphome UI. Thanks for the info, I couldnt find it by myself